# Set parent transform so child transform will be (0,0,0) with no rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a gameobject with following hierarchy(each spaced offse mean it's child):

```
ASO
  CPO
    ARC
    Tr
      BabyPrefab
```

I've tried following, but that didnt work, idk why.

```
var _go = GameObject.Find("BabyPrefab");
var _arOrig = GameObject.Find("ASO");
_go.transform.SetParent(null, true);
_arOrig.transform.SetParent(_go.transform, true);

_go.transform.position = Vector3.zero;

_go.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

_arOrig.transform.SetParent(null, true);

_go.transform.SetParent(_arOrig.trackablesParent);
```

I want the BabyPrefab gameobject's transform to become position = (0,0,0) and Quartenion.identity.

And all other gameobjects in this hierarchy become transformed to save their relative coordinates to BabyPrefab.

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: Works for me. What is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: @Aybe Edited. And all other gameobjects in this hierarchy become transformed to save their relative coordinates to BabyPrefab.

Comment: @Saif And all other gameobjects in this hierarchy become transformed to save their relative coordinates to BabyPrefab.

Comment: Have you tried second overload? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

Comment: @Aybe I did it.

Comment: `_go.transform.position = Vector3.zero`? Have you tried `localPosition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform.Translate` on `ASO` with the negative of `BabyPrefab`'s position in world space to move `ASO` such that the position of `BabyPrefab` goes to `Vector3.zero`:

```
var _go = GameObject.Find("BabyPrefab");
var _arOrig = GameObject.Find("ASO");
_arOrig.transform.Translate(-_go.transform.position, Space.World);
```

Then, get the world rotation of `BabyPrefab` in angle/axis form:

```
float babyAngle;
Vector3 babyAxis;
_go.transform.rotation.ToAngleAxis(out babyAngle, out babyAxis);
```

Then, rotate `ASO` around that axis going through `Vector3.zero` by the negative of that angle:

```
_arOrig.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, babyAxis, -babyAngle);
```

Altogether:

```
var _go = GameObject.Find("BabyPrefab");
var _arOrig = GameObject.Find("ASO");
_arOrig.transform.Translate(-_go.transform.position, Space.World);

float babyAngle;
Vector3 babyAxis;
_go.transform.rotation.ToAngleAxis(out babyAngle, out babyAxis);

_arOrig.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, babyAxis, -babyAngle);
```